# Moved app to Default Application Pool with ApplicationPoolIdentity and there are permission errors

Tags: php, iis, iis-10, laravel

Running a PHP 8.2 app.

I changed the app to use the Default Application Pool under the user  `ApplicationPoolIdentity` instead of the previous Custom pool and custom account, but now I get:

> The stream or file C:\inepub...\logfile.log could not be opened in
> append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied

I then thought I need to add the user `IUSR` to the users under security and give it all the permissions, but it still did not work.

How can I fix the permission when using `ApplicationPoolIdentity`?

Edit: I even followed this guide and added `IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool`, but still not good:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities#securing-resources